# Scipy minimize does not take constraints into account

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am new to programmation and I tried to solve a maths optimization problem using Python.

The idea of the problem is to minimize the value of a function while some constraints are respected. This might seem very straightforward, however for some reason the result I get clearly does not satisfy the constraints.

The function in question is the following (I do not have enough reputation points to post images of LaTeX equations):

f(a,b,c,d) = 2*a + 3*b + c + 2*d

With the following constraints:

- a+b=2
- c+d=8
- a+c=3
- b+d=7

I used scipy.optimize.minimize in Python to try to solve it, here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize as min

def f(x):
    return 2*x[0] + 3*x[1] + x[2] + 2*x[3]

cons = ({'type' : 'eq','fun': lambda x: np.array([x[0]+x[1]-2])},
{'type' : 'eq','fun': lambda x: np.array([x[2]+x[3]-8])}, 
{'type':'eq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[0]+x[2]-3])}, 
{'type':'eq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[1]+x[3]-7])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[0]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[1]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[2]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[3]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun':f})

u = min(f,[1.5,0.5,1.5,6.5],constraints=cons,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'Disp':True,'maxiter':2})

print(u)
print(f(u.x))
```

It gives me some values for a,b,c,d that do not satisfy the equalities. I did try to change the optimization method but it did not help.

Any advice would be really appreciated, thank you for reading!

Comment: could it be that you are using the wrong method? from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) seems like the only method available for a constraint minimization are COBYLA and SLSQP

Comment: When i use SLSQP it just gives me my initial guess back... and for COBYLA it says that it can't handle constraints of the type 'eq'

Comment: I tried with many different initial conditions and the optimal value is always `19` which is the same value as you get for your initial conditions (using the `SLSQP` method). Could be that you get your original values returned because they already give you the optimal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective function is linear, and your equality constraints are linear, so the problem is simple enough to do by hand.  If you do that, you'll observe a couple interesting facts:

- One of your constraints is redundant.  For example, you can drop `a + c = 3`, because that equation is implied by the other three.
- You are left with three linear equations and four unknowns. The solution to such a system is a straight line in the four-dimensional space.  The interesting thing about that line is that your objective function is *constant* on it.  It has the value 19 at every point on the line.  So (taking into account the inequality constraints), every point on the line with nonnegative coordinates is a solution.
  In particular, your starting point `[1.5,0.5,1.5,6.5]` is on the line, so it is a solution.  So is `[1.9, 0.1, 1.1, 6.9]`, `[1.65, 0.35, 1.35, 6.65]`, or in fact any point of the form `[0, 2, 3, 5] + a*[1, -1, -1, 1]` for which the components are not negative.

Answer (score 1):

Hi from the  [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) seems like the only method available for a constraint minimization are COBYLA and SLSQP, and in particular, when using a *'eq'* constraint, just the SLSQP one. 
This might work:

```
u = min(f,[1.5,0.5,1.5,6.5],constraints=cons,method='SLSQP')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however when I use this method it gives me my initial guess back

Comment: by changing the initial guess the value of the output changes `u = min(f,[1.5,3.5,1.5,6.5],constraints=cons,options={'maxiter':20})`        `x: array([ 2.75, -0.75,  0.25,  7.75])`

Comment: I forgot to mention that all the values had to be positive, I added it to the constraints in the code here:

```python
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[0]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[1]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[2]])},
{'type':'ineq' , 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[3]])},
```